# WPF C# Image MouseDown to switch pages

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mouseevent, mousedown

I have 3 Images with Mouse Down event like this :

```
        private void button12_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) // Back to choose story menu page.
    {

       //if button 2 is pressed then show FoodKing
      // if button 1 is pressed then show Grasshopper
        stackPanelHome.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        pageTransition1.ShowPage(What to put in here?);


    }

    private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) // Food fit for a king.
    {
        FoodKing controlpage = new FoodKing(); // Calling user control page          
        stackPanelHome.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        pageTransition1.ShowPage(controlpage); 

    }

private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) // Grasshopper
{
    GrasshopperMenu controlpage = new GrasshopperMenu(); / Calling user control page
    stackPanelHome.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    pageTransition1.ShowPage(controlpage); 
}
```

In the first page , there is 2 icon , 1 is FoodKing , 1 is Grasshopper then they choose which image to press on and each icon have many buttons and leads to else where , so i create a menu page to revert the user back to the page that they have selected in the beginning ( FoodKing or GrassHopper) . But how do i do this? See my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Page currentPage;

private void button12_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) // Back to choose story menu page.
{
    stackPanelHome.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    if(currentPage != null)
    {
        pageTransition1.ShowPage(currentPage);
    }
}

private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) // Food fit for a king.
{
    FoodKing controlpage = new FoodKing(); // Calling user control page          
    stackPanelHome.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    pageTransition1.ShowPage(controlpage); 
    currentPage = controlpage;
}

private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) // Grasshopper
{
    GrasshopperMenu controlpage = new GrasshopperMenu(); // Calling user control page
    stackPanelHome.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    pageTransition1.ShowPage(controlpage); 
    currentPage = controlpage;
}
```